# QMediaPlayer on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, ffmpeg

I know that the QMultimediaWidgets are not supported for C++. I am developing a native application for Android as well. Since I don't use QML I need a way of playing my videos in the application. I want to use the QMediaPlayer since I rely on the signals and slots. Is there any manually developed backend which works on Android or a solution how I can render the video myself still using QMediaPlayer?

Is there a way I can developed such a backend myself using ffmpeg or any available program on Android? Will there be any update for this in Qt soon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QtMultimediaWidgets is not supported on Android so you need to use the QML elements. What you can theoretically try is to embed a QML scene using the MediaPlayer and VideoOutput elements in your QWidget-based app using [QWidget::createWindowContainer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer). Once you see this can be done, you can get your QMediaPlayer object from QML using the [mediaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html#mediaObject-prop) property of the MediaPlayer QML element. I never tried to do something like this actually.

You may also try to use another plugin like [QtAV](https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV), but you may lose acceleration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am currently trying to load a QML script dynamically and setting the source of the MediaPlayer and accessing everything via invokeMethod calls. The sound can be heard but the video does not appear although the emulator for Android doesnt print any error related to the video encoding. I use a widget created with QWidget::createWindowContainer() and it takes some space but no video is there.

Comment: Did you try on a real device?

Comment: Not yet. I have no real device available at the moment but various emulators didn't show the video although I used an encoding listed as supported by the Android documentation. Maybe I will try QML application only.

Comment: Android emulators are typically not to be trusted.

Comment: Btw. I tried to compile QtAv for Android but it said avutils are missing. On the emulator I get a message like "NuPlayer: onSetVideoSurface no video decoder" when autoplaying a video with QML. Does that mean the codec is wrong or the emulator simply has no decoder? The sound usually works but I don't see any video.

Comment: Avutils is a dependency. You need to add it. But I suggest you use the default Qt plugin if possible.